# test the series for absolute or conditional convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Test the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \left( \dfrac{2^n+n^3}{3^n+n^2} \right)$ for absolute or conditional convergence. If you use any of the tests (results), then the required conditions for these tests should be evident:

[image]

please help with this question
not sure about what my professor asking,
(test the series for absolute or conditional convergence. if you use any the tests the required conditions for these tests should be evident). 
Thank you

Comment: Decide wether this series converges or not; there are many criteria you can use to check for absolute or conditional convergence (I guess the ratio test should already be successful).

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\dfrac{2ⁿ+n³}{3ⁿ+n²}}{\dfrac{2ⁿ}{3ⁿ}}=1,$$ $∑((2^n)/(3^n))$ converges. Thus $∑(-1)^{n-1}\left( \dfrac{2^n+n^3}{3^n+n^2} \right)$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Please use LaTeX to format your question, this is very difficult to read and understand: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference